# Ajax Based Display Not Accurate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, joomla

I'm building a Joomla module that uses slideDown and ajax of jQuery.

The way it works is that it populates the slideDown div, compute the div child element with highest height, and resizes the containing div height for display.

Problem is if the page is not cached (i.e. if it is on first load of the page) the height is not displayed properly as below

[image: Wrong Display]

But on second click and so on, it displays correctly as follows

[image: Right Display]

I'm thinking it is because the contents of the div child element are not completely populated before the height is computed, hence a false height is generated. I've tried some things to ensure that does not happen - right now I'm using a callback function along with the function that populates the div tag.

Quick help will be highly appreciated, thanks!

Edit - here's the code that populates

```
menuItemAjax: function (urlContent, dataContent) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: urlContent,
        data: dataContent, // data to send along with url
        complete: function () {
            //console.log("Process completed");
        },
        success: function (returnedData) {
            WetvCreateHtml.popDropDownDiv(returnedData, function() {

                var ddChildren = dropdownDiv.children(), highestHeight = 0;
                ddChildren.each(function(){
                    if (jQuery(this).height() > highestHeight) {
                        highestHeight = jQuery(this).height();
                    }
                });
                dropdownDiv.animate({ height: highestHeight });

            });

        },
        error: function () {
            //console.log("Error occured");
        },
        statusCode: {
            404: function() {
                //console.log("Page not found");
            }
        }
    });
},

popDropDownDiv: function(returnedData, callback) {
    dropdownDiv.html(returnedData);

    if (typeof(callback) == "function") {
        callback();
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to show some basic code.

Comment: Added the code responsible for the changes.

Comment: Are the children visible and added to the document?

Comment: Yes they are, also the value of the height of the child with the highest height is correct but that of the containing div is incorrect, on first page load.